# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, battery

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS dual booted with Windows 7 , when i am with windows 7, computer performs normally, but when i switched to Ubuntu it roaring like anything , also heats up quicklyand battery is less durable, i asked about this issue with several peoples, but problem remains unchanged, what i have to do to solve this issue? please help in this regard..

Comment: You need to run this command in terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and post output here.

Comment: No command 'lcpci' found, did you mean:
 Command 'lspci' from package 'pciutils' (main)
lcpci: command not found
No command 'ergrep' found, did you mean:
 Command 'egrep' from package 'grep' (main)
 Command 'rgrep' from package 'grep' (main)
ergrep: command not found

Comment: Sry, it is "lspci -k |  egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2". That was a typo.

Comment: How to attach screenshot to your comment. . ?

Comment: what this command about.?

Comment: Do not do it as a comment, [edit] your post instead. And can you just select text from terminal and paste it there. You can use right mouse click.

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
 Subsystem: Dell Device 0598
 Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series]
 Subsystem: Dell Radeon HD 7670M
 Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci

Comment: This command will show what graphical adapters you have and which drivers are installed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post information THERE, not in comments.

Comment: now what i have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution will be to upgrade Ubuntu to 14.04 LTS.
You will get a newer kernel, graphical stack and will be able to install new AMD proprietary drivers.

New kernel and new drivers must handle power consumption better.

You can upgrade your system by running

```
do-release-upgrade
```

in terminal.

Then follow directions to upgrade to 14.04. This will take some time and needs good internet connection.

Comment: How to upgrade to 14.04 ?LTS

Comment: Is it with command?

Comment: About how much data it may take . . ?

Comment: I do not know exactly, but approx 1-2 GB I think. It depends on what software is installed.